# Firebase Detecting if user exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

How Can I Check user exists in Firebase auth in `Signup` Button via react native?

**This is my Login Page Code:**

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            response: ''
        }
        this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this)
        this.login = this.login.bind(this)
    }

    async signUp() {
        try {
            await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            this.setState({
                response: 'Account Created!'
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.navigator.push({
                    id: 'App'
                })
            }, 500)
        } catch (error) {
            this.setState({
                response: error.toString()
            })
        }
    }
    async login() {
        try {
            await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            this.setState({
                response: 'user login in'
            })

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.navigator.push({
                    id: 'App'
                })
            })

        } catch (error) {
            this.setState({
                response: error.toString()
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.containerInputes}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholderTextColor="gray"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        style={styles.inputText}
                        onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholderTextColor="gray"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        style={styles.inputText}
                        password={true}
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                    />
                </View>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={this.login}
                    style={[styles.loginButton, styles.button]}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={styles.textButton}
                    >Login</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={this.signUp}
                    style={[styles.loginButton, styles.button]}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={styles.textButton}
                    >Signup</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use only one button for signup and login? If so, you could do the signInWithEmailAndPassword and if the error shows that the user does not exist, you can offer to signup. Treat the exception on the catch

Comment: I have 2 Buttons,  a Login Button and  a Signup Button, But I want When user want to signup it tell to user This email is taken or no

Comment: Just call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and look for the `auth/email-already-in-use` error code - see the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword).

Comment: Thanks, I'm new in firebase can you update my code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail API. It takes an email and returns a promise that resolves with the list of providers linked to that email if it is already registered:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#fetchsigninmethodsforemail

Comment: Thanks. I'm new in firebase, where should i add that code? Can you tell me an exampe please?

Comment: You would first ask the user to provide the email, you call this API, if the array is empty, show the sign up page where you call createUserWithEmailAndPassword. Otherwise if the array returned contains the string 'password', then show the sign in screen and ask the user to provide the password.

Comment: What about the Sign in with Apple without providing email? How do you check that type of account? (Sign in With Apple will be mandatory on the iOS platform)

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to use the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` API. It returns an array. If the array is empty, it means the user has never signed up/signed in to your app with the sign in methods you have used in your app.

This is an example with Google signin.

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
        let token = result.credential.accessToken;
        let user = result.user;

        firebase
            .auth()
            .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(user.email)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('result', result);
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Handle Errors here.
        }
```

Comment: signInWithPopup(provider) will create user so in "then" response always will be "google.com"

Answer (score 4):

For me `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail()` only works with an email that is registered with email/password and not working for emails registered with Apple, LinkedIn or other providers.

> For solution to this, I came up with following work around:

```
auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, 'some-random-password')  // Password should be really long to avoid actually logging in :)
.then((response) => {
    // TODO : Avoid this block
})
.catch((error) => {
    if(error.code === 'auth/wrong-password'){
        // TODO : If here then it means account already exists...
    }

    if(error.code === 'auth/user-not-found'){
        // TODO : If here then you guessed it... you can create a new account.
    }
})
```

*I'm sure there is a proper solution for this and I will update this answer when I find it.*

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple.
Add a then() and catch() to your firebase method in signUp function.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
.then(()=>{
    console.log('Signup successful.');
    this.setState({
            response: 'Account Created!'
        })
   })
.catch((error)=> {
    console.log(error.code);
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

**Information on different Error Codes:**

- *auth/email-already-in-use*

  Thrown if there already exists an account with the given email address.
- *auth/invalid-email*

  Thrown if the email address is not valid.
- *auth/operation-not-allowed*

  Thrown if email/password accounts are not enabled. Enable email/password accounts in the Firebase Console, under the Auth tab.
- *auth/weak-password*

  Thrown if the password is not strong enough.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the account will be created if it's not. These won't work in cases wherein you want to give the user an instant feedback on input blur if the email is already in use.

Comment: `auth/email-already-in-use` not triggering if you have a FB account and create a new Sign in with Apple account. The Facebook account will be deleted, or linked (if its email was verified) as per: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/liu/firebase-talk/ms_NVQem_Cw/8g7BFk1IAAAJ

Answer (score 0):

The old ways do not work anymore as of now. The following piece of code worked for me

```js
if(res._tokenResponse.isNewUser){
 // New User signed up
} else {
 // Existing user signed in
}
```