# check if user is already exists in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I started with firebase (web) I would like to know how to programmatically verify that a user already exists in the firebase user table without using the

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(...)
```

I would like to know if there is not another method to directly verify if the user does not exist.
thank..

Comment: search about fetchProvidersForEmail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Detecting if user exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615808/firebase-detecting-if-user-exists)