# How can I check if user exists in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I finally got my authentication to work in terms of creating users and logging in and out.  But now, I want to implement something that checks if the user already exists in Firebase.  I've looked it up but can't seem to find a concrete answer.

For example, if my email address is: abc12@gmail.com and someone else tries to signup with the same email address, how do I tell them it's already taken?

```
login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .then((u) => {
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

signup(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .then((u) => {
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615808/firebase-detecting-if-user-exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Detecting if user exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615808/firebase-detecting-if-user-exists)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The error that is returned from method `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` has a `code` property. Per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) the error `code` **auth/email-already-in-use**:

> Thrown if there already exists an account with the given email
> address.

At very minimum you can utilize conditional statements such as `if`/`else` or `switch` to check for that `code` and display/log/dispatch/etc a message or code to the user:

```
fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
  .then(u => {})
  .catch(error => {
     switch (error.code) {
        case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
          console.log(`Email address ${this.state.email} already in use.`);
          break;
        case 'auth/invalid-email':
          console.log(`Email address ${this.state.email} is invalid.`);
          break;
        case 'auth/operation-not-allowed':
          console.log(`Error during sign up.`);
          break;
        case 'auth/weak-password':
          console.log('Password is not strong enough. Add additional characters including special characters and numbers.');
          break;
        default:
          console.log(error.message);
          break;
      }
  });
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Checking inside a catch is correct, but you are missing break in the switch.

Answer (score 24):

There's a simpler answer in the case of firebase admin sdk:

```js
const uidExists = auth().getUser(uid).then(() => true).catch(() => false))
```

```js
const emailExists = auth().getUserByEmail(email).then(() => true).catch(() => false))
```

Comment: note that these only work server side (admin SDK), not client side.

Answer (score 9):

I use `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` like this:

```
import { getAuth, fetchSignInMethodsForEmail } from 'firebase/auth';

const auth = getAuth();
let signInMethods = await fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(auth, email);
if (signInMethods.length > 0) {
  //user exists
} else {
   //user does not exist
}
```

[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#fetchsigninmethodsforemail) for reference

**Update Sept 15 2023**: Firebase now disables this feature by default to avoid Email Enumerarion. According to Google:

> Email enumeration is a type of brute-force attack in which a malicious actor attempts to guess or confirm users in a system by passing an email address to the API and checking the response.

You can still use this feature by enabling it in your Firebase console by navigating to Authentication -> Settings -> User Actions and then disabling email enumeration protection:
[image]

Make sure to read about the [risk of disabling this on your platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection)

Comment: I don't know if this is a ideal way as it requires auth isntance. the OP is wanting to check if user exists in logged out state in which I don't think this answer would work

Comment: @rbtmr Thats not true. The question states "I want to implement something that checks if the user already exists in Firebase". Thanks for the downvote broski.

Comment: @DustinSpengler
"For example, if my email address is: abc12@gmail.com and someone else tries to signup with the same email address, how do I tell them it's already taken?"

Comment: @DustinSpengler no it doesnt. i ran into the same issue last month,

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection

Comment: "A list of sign-in methods for a specified email address is no longer returned when calling the createAuthUri REST API or the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail client SDK method on all platforms."

Comment: @rbtmr This is documentation from Firebase Admin

Comment: @DustinSpengler "or the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail client SDK method on all platforms."

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7644#issuecomment-1751301783

not admin related.

Answer (score 0):

```
from firebase_admin import auth

user = auth.get_user_by_email(email)
print('Successfully fetched user data exists: {0}'.format(user.uid))
```

In python admin server